# Why does the slash key "/" not have an ASCII value of 47?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ascii

I have just reassigned a hotkey in our game to use the slash key "/", which according to the ASCII table should have a value of 47. But it's not firing. It fires for all my other standard keys. When I step through the code I see that the keyEventRecord shows the key value as 191 or 111 if I use the slash on the  numeric keyboard. Why is this so? Do I need to convert it somehow?

Just for clarification, I store the key value as an int.

Comment: can you replicate the bug on another computer?

Comment: Are you mixing up key scan codes and character codes?

Comment: Read some documentation, those are [virtual-key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), not ASCII.

Answer (score 5):

Keyboards do not know anything about ASCII.  They only know about **scan codes**, which are vendor-specific IDs for the actual keys.

When processed, scan codes get normalized in vendor-independent **virtual key codes**.  191 is `VK_OEM_2` (used for the `/?` key in US keyboards) and 111 is `VK_DIVIDE`.

When dispatched to UI windows, virtual key codes get converted into **character codes** in `WM_CHAR` and `WM_UNICHAR` messages.  These are human-readable characters, such as ASCII characters (though `WM_CHAR` actually presents characters in ANSI/UTF-16 encoding, and `WM_UNICHAR` in UTF-32 encoding).

So, you are clearly processing keyboard events, such as `WM_KEYDOWN/UP` or `ReadConsoleInput()`, that are reporting **virtual key codes** when you are expecting **character codes** instead.

For many ASCII characters, their **virtual key code** and their **character code** are the same value, eg:

```
#define VK_BACK           0x08
#define VK_TAB            0x09
#define VK_RETURN         0x0D
#define VK_SPACE          0x20

/*
 * VK_0 - VK_9 are the same as ASCII '0' - '9' (0x30 - 0x39)
 * VK_A - VK_Z are the same as ASCII 'A' - 'Z' (0x41 - 0x5A)
 */
```

However, for other ASCII characters, their **virtual key code** and their **character code** have different values, eg:

```
#define VK_OEM_1          0xBA   // ';:' for US
#define VK_OEM_PLUS       0xBB   // '+' any country
#define VK_OEM_COMMA      0xBC   // ',' any country
#define VK_OEM_MINUS      0xBD   // '-' any country
#define VK_OEM_PERIOD     0xBE   // '.' any country
#define VK_OEM_2          0xBF   // '/?' for US
#define VK_OEM_3          0xC0   // '`~' for US
#define VK_OEM_4          0xDB  //  '[{' for US
#define VK_OEM_5          0xDC  //  '\|' for US
#define VK_OEM_6          0xDD  //  ']}' for US
#define VK_OEM_7          0xDE  //  ''"' for US
```

Read MSDN for more information:

[About Keyboard Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. This code was originally written by a colleague and I can see now where he handles the exceptions like you have indicated (eg VK_OEM_3) He hadn't put one in for the slash. I'll do that now. Much obliged for the help.